# How to disable all price and transaction round off in magento

Tags: rounding

I am working on magento 1.7. all price and calculation in round off. i want to disable this feature but don't get it how to disable it please help me. please see following screenshot [image]

Comment: See here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13111/change-currency-precision

Answer (score 1):

There is no real way to do this. What you might do is looking for every `round()`, `sprintf()` and functions like this, but at least for tax calculation it is done automatically, because float is limited to 64bit.

Comment: are you sure this is done by modify core files ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand: Do you asking whether this is possible without modifying core files? I think it is possible with a lot of rewrites and a lot of work

Comment: do you have any idea where i can verify this any file so i can assure this was due to modification of core file because i checked code/core/mage/catalog/model/product.php but its same as fresh magento downloaded from magentocommerce

Comment: This is a hard task. Theoretically you can just download a fresh copy of magento with the correct version and run a `diff` between these two, BUT magento makes silent updates to the version, this means, you can't be sure, wether the diff is an update from magento or a modification to the file.