# Change currency precision

Tags: currency, locale

What is the best way to change the currency's precision?

I have a store that uses Euro as the currency, but I want to change the precision from 2 decimal places to 3.

I know that the locale data is stored under /lib/Zend/Locale/Data but is this really the best place to change this sort of information.

Comment: I would be concerned about the reliability of changing this. I believe that Magento (unfortunately) has some hardcoded assumptions regarding currency precision. Also, `Zend_Locale_Data` makes some assumptions about the relative location of the localization XML files :-/

Comment: Yeah the 2 is hard coded in place for Magento :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok first of all I saw the event `currency_display_options_forming` and I thought that this would be so easy, but sadly that was not the case :( You can use this event to change the display of the currency across the whole site but the follow code stops the precision from working in all cases.

Under `Mage_Directory_Model_Currency` there is a function `formatPrecision`. Here it checks for the options and if it does not find one for precision it will hard code it to 2!

So the first thing I did as Marius said is to rewrite the `Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::format` I chose to set it up with xml (great minds think alike)

```
public function format($price, $options = array(), $includeContainer = true, $addBrackets = false)
{
    return $this->formatPrecision(
        $price,
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_ALLOW), // Mage uses '2' here
        $options,
        $includeContainer,
        $addBrackets
    );
}
```

But that only changes the display. Most of the price displays all call `Mage_Core_Model_Store::roundPrice` and this again has a hard coded 2, I am starting to think this was a bad idea.

```
public function roundPrice($price)
{
    return round($price, 2);
}
```

So the obvious thing now is to rewrite the roundPrice function and again use the same xml config value.

```
public function roundPrice($fPrice)
{
    return round($fPrice, Mage::getStoreConfig(Sitewards_Currency_Model_Format::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_ALLOW));
}
```

Now that covers most of the front-end if you also want to change this in the admin section that would involve changing templates and rewriting at least `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Price`

```
public function getEscapedValue($iIndex=null)
{
    $fValue = $this->getValue();

    if (!is_numeric($fValue)) {
        return null;
    }

    return number_format($fValue, Mage::getStoreConfig(Sitewards_Currency_Model_Format::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_ALLOW), null, '');
}
```

One not on the template front, the one I know about now is `catalog/product/edit/price/tier.phtml` as again that has `<?php echo sprintf('%.2f', $_item['price']) ?>`

On one final note the admin grid actually does work with the first event `currency_display_options_forming`.

I will update this answer the more I find out, but it is still a work in progress.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can override the method `Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::format`.
Right now it looks like this:

```
 public function format($price, $options=array(), $includeContainer = true, $addBrackets = false)
{
    return $this->formatPrecision($price, 2, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
}
```

The second parameter for `formatPrecision` is the number of decimals.  Change it to :

```
 public function format($price, $options=array(), $includeContainer = true, $addBrackets = false)
{
    return $this->formatPrecision($price, 3, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
}
```

Or if you want to be "politically correct", to this:

```
 public function format($price, $options=array(), $includeContainer = true, $addBrackets = false)
{
    return $this->formatPrecision($price, Mage::getStoreConfig('some/path/here'), $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
}
```

and define a config setting that you can change later.

Comment: Oh Marius I wish it was that easy ;) that is about a third of what I have done so far. Will post the complete (as in how far we have tested) answer soon.

Comment: @DavidManners I imagined it was not only this, but I thought that a pattial answer is better than no answer.

Comment: Yup you are right. I am typing up my slightly less partial answer now also :)

Comment: Please I am new to Magento 2, I need the full solution files.